# Pentaho Report Designer: How to create a chart based on an OLAP cube?

Tags: pentaho

Using Pentaho Report Designer, I can successfully display my OLAP cube's data as a table.

But when I want to display the same data as a chart, it always fail saying "CHART.USER_NO_DATA_AVAILABLE".

Actually, I don't really know what I should enter for category-column and value-columns. I tried:

```
category-column = [Area].[prefecture]
value-columns = [[Product].[Product.Product].[All Products].[productA]]
```

And any other variation I could think of, but no success. Any idea? Thanks!
*My OLAP cube is a Pentaho Analysis: sales count for each product and prefecture.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

[Product].[Product.Product].[All Products].[productA]

You only need the extra square brackets around the entire fieldname if it's a formula.

Or pick the field from the dropdown..  then you know you have the right one!

If you're doing a timeseries xy, note you have to repeat the category column value as many times as the value column.

also make sure you have a series name too.